# How can I handle input string, during the process of if, else if, else including Integer.parseInt?

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I would like to handle this situation about inputting wrong string, but error keeps happening because of the else if argument.

Tried try, catch but don't know how to apply it to this code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class game
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("let's start the multiplication game.");
    System.out.println("which times table do you want to choose?");
    System.out.println("if you want to do it by your choice, please input number among 2~9. Or if you want to do it randomly, please input number 0");
    System.out.println("press \"q\" if you want to quit");
    System.out.println("==>");

    String input;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    input = s.nextLine();

    int answer;
    int multiplier = (int)(Math.random()*8+2);
    int random = (int)(Math.random()*8+2);

    if (input.equals("q"))
    {
        System.out.print("quit the game.");
    }

    else if (Integer.parseInt(input) == 0) 
    {
        System.out.println(random+"times table has been made automatically.");
        System.out.print(random+" X "+multiplier+" = "+"? input your answer ==> ");
        answer = s.nextInt();

        if (answer == random*multiplier)
        {
            System.out.print("You're right!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Wrong! The right answer is "+random*multiplier+".");
        }

    }

    else if (Integer.parseInt(input)>=2 && Integer.parseInt(input)<=9)
    {   
        int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
        System.out.println("You chose"+number+" times table.");
        System.out.print(number+" X "+multiplier+" = "+"? input your answer ==> ");
        answer = s.nextInt();

        if (answer == number*multiplier)
        {
            System.out.print("You're right!");
        }
        else
        {               
            System.out.print("Wrong! The right answer is "+number*multiplier+".");
        }
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.print("Error. Please try again.");
    }   
 }
}
```

I expect the result from the else block, but when I input wrong string like `"c"` or `"f"` and etc, number format exception error: For input string: `"c"` (or `"f"` and etc) happens. Thanks for reading this, and hope you solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
int check = 0;

try{
   check = Integer.parseInt(input);

}catch(NumberFormatException e){
   System.out.println("Wrong input");
   continue;
}
```

If you loop this input processing,if it enters catch,you may take input again or you can do what you want when invalid input is entered.If there is no exception,check is your input value,then you can use it in your if and else-if statements like

```
if(check>0){
   ...
}
```

Comment: I should study more about try catch continue usage. Anyway thanks! I will try this approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

Before Else blocks, you can parse the input like this:

```
if (input.equals("q")) {
  System.out.print("quit the game.");
  return;
}

int parsedInput = 0;
try {
  parsedInput = Integer.parseInt(input);
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
  System.out.print("Error. Please try again.");
  return;
}
```

Then you can write if-else for integer input like below:

```
if (parsedInput == 0) { ... }
else if (parsedInput >= 2 && parsedInput <= 9) {...}
```

Last else is not needed because I moved it to catch block.

Comment: I think I should learn more about if-return style coding. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

try this it can handle exception

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("let's start the multiplication game.");
        System.out.println("which times table do you want to choose?");
        System.out.println(
                "if you want to do it by your choice, please input number among 2~9. Or if you want to do it randomly, please input number 0");
        System.out.println("press \"q\" if you want to quit");
        System.out.println("==>");

        String input;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = s.nextLine();

        int answer;
        int multiplier = (int) (Math.random() * 8 + 2);
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 8 + 2);

        if (input.equals("q")) {
            System.out.print("quit the game.");
        }
        try {
            int check_input = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if (check_input == 0) {
                System.out.println(random + "times table has been made automatically.");
                System.out.print(random + " X " + multiplier + " = " + "? input your answer ==> ");
                answer = s.nextInt();

                if (answer == random * multiplier) {
                    System.out.print("You're right!");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("Wrong! The right answer is " + random * multiplier + ".");
                }

            } else if (check_input >= 2 && check_input <= 9) {
                int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
                System.out.println("You chose" + number + " times table.");
                System.out.print(number + " X " + multiplier + " = " + "? input your answer ==> ");
                answer = s.nextInt();

                if (answer == number * multiplier) {
                    System.out.print("You're right!");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("Wrong! The right answer is " + number * multiplier + ".");
                }
            }

            else {
                System.out.print("Error. Please try again.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Error. Please try again.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Finally got it how to use try catch in this code.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check the user provided input is number or not. Before parsing it.

I have added new `isNumberic` method which is returning boolean flag depending user's input and verify it.

public class Game {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("let's start the multiplication game.");
    System.out.println("which times table do you want to choose?");
    System.out.println(
            "if you want to do it by your choice, please input number among 2~9. Or if you want to do it randomly, please input number 0");
    System.out.println("press \"q\" if you want to quit");
    System.out.println("==>");

    String input;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    input = s.nextLine();

    int answer;
    int multiplier = (int) (Math.random() * 8 + 2);
    int random = (int) (Math.random() * 8 + 2);

    Game game = new Game();
    boolean isvalid = game.isNumeric(input);
    if (input.equals("q")) {
        System.out.print("quit the game.");
    }

    else if (isvalid && Integer.parseInt(input) == 0) {
        System.out.println(random + "times table has been made automatically.");
        System.out.print(random + " X " + multiplier + " = " + "? input your answer ==> ");
        answer = s.nextInt();

        if (answer == random * multiplier) {
            System.out.print("You're right!");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Wrong! The right answer is " + random * multiplier + ".");
        }

    }

    else if (isvalid && Integer.parseInt(input) >= 2 && Integer.parseInt(input) <= 9) {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
        System.out.println("You chose" + number + " times table.");
        System.out.print(number + " X " + multiplier + " = " + "? input your answer ==> ");
        answer = s.nextInt();

        if (answer == number * multiplier) {
            System.out.print("You're right!");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Wrong! The right answer is " + number * multiplier + ".");
        }
    }

    else {
        System.out.print("Error. Please try again.");
    }
}

public static boolean isNumeric(String str)
{
    for (char c : str.toCharArray())
    {
        if (!Character.isDigit(c)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll try it after studying more related syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that you are getting this error because you are calling `Integer.parseInt` on a string variable which doesn't contain an `Integer`. What you should be doing is putting a check once you get the input to check if the string contains what you need. Something like below

```
while (true)
    {
// Check that the input is between 0 and 9 or q.
        if (!((input.charAt(0) >= '0' && input.charAt(0) <= '9') || input.charAt(0) == 'q'))
        {
            // If it is not, ask for input again.
            System.out.println("Input is not correct. If you want to do it by your choice, please input number among 2~9. Or if you want to do it randomly, please input number 0");
            input = s.nextLine();
        }
        else {
            // If input is correct, break this look.
            break;
        }
    }
```

Below is the whole code

```
public class game
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("let's start the multiplication game.");
    System.out.println("which times table do you want to choose?");
    System.out.println("if you want to do it by your choice, please input number among 2~9. Or if you want to do it randomly, please input number 0");
    System.out.println("press \"q\" if you want to quit");
    System.out.println("==>");

    String input;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    input = s.nextLine();
    while (true)
    {
        if (!((input.charAt(0) >= '0' && input.charAt(0) <= '9') || input.charAt(0) == 'q'))
        {
            System.out.println("Input is not correct. If you want to do it by your choice, please input number among 2~9. Or if you want to do it randomly, please input number 0");
            input = s.nextLine();
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    int answer;
    int multiplier = (int) (Math.random() * 8 + 2);
    int random = (int) (Math.random() * 8 + 2);

    if (input.equals("q"))
    {
        System.out.print("quit the game.");
    }

    else if (Integer.parseInt(input) == 0)
    {
        System.out.println(random + "times table has been made automatically.");
        System.out.print(random + " X " + multiplier + " = " + "? input your answer ==> ");
        answer = s.nextInt();

        if (answer == random * multiplier)
        {
            System.out.print("You're right!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Wrong! The right answer is " + random * multiplier + ".");
        }

    }

    else if (Integer.parseInt(input) >= 2 && Integer.parseInt(input) <= 9)
    {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
        System.out.println("You chose" + number + " times table.");
        System.out.print(number + " X " + multiplier + " = " + "? input your answer ==> ");
        answer = s.nextInt();

        if (answer == number * multiplier)
        {
            System.out.print("You're right!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Wrong! The right answer is " + number * multiplier + ".");
        }
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.print("Error. Please try again.");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the kind explanation. But still can't understand that the result from input.charAt(0) can be comparable with other string like '0' or '9' by using >= or <=. Because those results are not integer type, aren't they?

Comment: @Kris Since both operand are of type `char`(0 and input.charAt(0)), you can do the comparison like this because JVM will promote this char to int at runtime to do this comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send values like a , b, c etc for 
Integer.parseInt(String s)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)
I have try catch block to catch numberformat exception with message to enter valid integer

```
public static void main(String args[]) {


    System.out.println("let's start the multiplication game.");
    System.out.println("which times table do you want to choose?");
    System.out.println("if you want to do it by your choice, please input number among 2~9. Or if you want to do it randomly, please input number 0");
    System.out.println("press \"q\" if you want to quit");
    System.out.println("==>");

    String input;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    input = s.nextLine();

    int answer;
    int multiplier = (int)(Math.random()*8+2);
    int random = (int)(Math.random()*8+2);
   try {
    if (input.equals("q"))
    {
        System.out.print("quit the game.");
    }

    else if (Integer.parseInt(input) == 0) 
    {
        System.out.println(random+"times table has been made automatically.");
        System.out.print(random+" X "+multiplier+" = "+"? input your answer ==> ");
        answer = s.nextInt();

        if (answer == random*multiplier)
        {
            System.out.print("You're right!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Wrong! The right answer is "+random*multiplier+".");
        }

    }

    else if (Integer.parseInt(input)>=2 && Integer.parseInt(input)<=9)
    {   
        int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
        System.out.println("You chose"+number+" times table.");
        System.out.print(number+" X "+multiplier+" = "+"? input your answer ==> ");
        answer = s.nextInt();

        if (answer == number*multiplier)
        {
            System.out.print("You're right!");
        }
        else
        {               
            System.out.print("Wrong! The right answer is "+number*multiplier+".");
        }
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.print("Error. Please try again.");
    }
   }
   catch (NumberFormatException e ) {
       System.out.print("pleae enter Valid integer");
   }
```

Comment: Thank you! Tried by this code and came to realize again how to use try catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Verify input in two separate if/else blocks. Add this code to your "else" statement to catch strings other than "q".

```
else{
    try {
        int inputNumber = Integer.parseInt(input);
        if(inputNumber == 0) {
            // code..
        } else if (inputNumber >= 2 && inputNumber <= 9) {
            // code..
        }
    } catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.print("Error. Please try again.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'll apply this try catch method to this code again.

Answer (score -1):

why don't use try catch?

```
    if (input.equals("q")) {
        System.out.print("quit the game.");
    }
    try {
       Integer i = Integer.parseInt(input);
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.print("Error. Please try again.");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Actually I tried, but had failed because didn't know exact usage. And now I could try again by you and others' advice! Thank you so much :)